# MKMapView how to create insertAnnotationAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, android-mapview, mkannotation

Due to performance reasons, I need to do a binary insert on my annotations list, but after I reached the part where I actually need to insert the annotation, I realized that my mapView is not the same as a NSMutableArray, so I cannot freely add an annotation in the middle of the list.

```
while (first <= last) {
    NSUInteger mid = (first + last)/2;
    if ([name compare:[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:mid]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        first = mid + 1;
    } else if ([name compare:[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:mid]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        last = mid - 1;
    } else {
        Annotation *destination = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        [destination setTitle:name];
        [destination setSubtitle:sub];
        [destination setCoordinate:coords];
        // method doesn't exist, but how do I create/simulate this?
        [mapView insertAnnotation:destination atIndex:mid];
        [destination release];
        return;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to extend mapview and create my own class to do this? If so, how would I go about adding the annotation at the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the order of annotations in MKMapView's `annotations` property.

The map view will display whichever annotations belong on the screen given the map view's current span and zoom. It may be that internally, the map view doesn't even store the annotations as an array. After all, it needs to be able to find all the annotations that are geographically close to the current region, and an array isn't the structure that's best suited for that.

If you want to keep the annotations sorted a certain way, you should maintain your own array. You can use that array to add the annotations to the map view when you set it up. For updates to the annotation list, however, you should add or remove only those annotations that you've added or removed from your list. That is, it's probably inefficient to remove the entire list of annotations and then add a whole new list when most of the annotations in the new list are the same.

Comment: Of course the order is important, because a sorted list of annotations allows me to do a binary search instead of a linear search. On a map with around 600 annotations, it decreases the average lookup from 300 comparisons to about 9.  Also, MKMapView is using a NSArray to hold the annotations as shown at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html but I'm not sure how to how to subclass it.

Comment: The `annotations` property provides an array, but that's not necessarily how MKMapView stores the data. Remember: properties are just a promise to provide certain accessors. Arrays are 1-dimensional objects, but MKMapView needs to sort annotations in 2 dimensions, and there are better structures for that than arrays. Also, there's no guarantee that MKMapView will preserve the order of annotations in the array that you give it. You should keep your own sorted list of annotations rather than rely on MKMapView to preserve your ordering for you.

Comment: After pondering about it, I believe your suggestion of making my own sorted list is a better idea. I don't have to keep track of the annotations through the actual mapview, I can just simulate it by making a copy and then adding to the actual mapview later. Although your answer is actually a question, and didn't provide an answer, your comment was useful, so I'll accept it anyway. Perhaps you could edit it to contain the answer?